# Ordering transaction in Ethereum - Proof of Stake

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, uniswap, ethereumjs

I am trying to understand the "Block position" of these 2 transactions in the same block (16334594):

- Tx1 has a position in block of 3, while Tx2 has a position of 7
- Tx2 (my transaction) has failed because Tx1 - performing the same task - has been put ahead in the block, making slippage thresholds of Tx2 not valid to execute the swap
- Tx2 has both higher Gas Price and Gas limit (also, looking at the body of the transactions, both had the same identical task - a swap on a Dex with similar quantities of the same tokens to be swapped)

How is it possible that Tx1 was mined before Tx2, having Tx2 a much higher gas price and limit, and a similar gas estimation for the execution (being similar in scope)? What can be the reasons why that happened?

The hash of Tx1 is https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc3b070a7563231c553f966964ca5e52cd489f97dfb416f65aa3d981283a073b3

Thanks a lot in advance!!

[image]